# do these conditions guarantee differentiability at a?

Tags: calculus

Let F, be a function that has the following properties:
For all H>0  there is a point "x" e ]a,a+H] such that f(x)=f(a)
Is this function differentiable at "a"?
For all G>0 there is a point "y" e]a,a+G] such that f(y) is different from f(a)

Is this function differentiable at "a

Comment: is that a constant  function line $y=a$

Comment: I assume you mean $x\in (a,H]$, a half-open interval. But do you mean $x\in (a,a+H]$? Otherwise, this doesn't make sense -- what if you choose $H=a/2$?

Comment: Ive changed the question, sorry for miswriting

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Your question is phrased as if to ask "do these conditions guarantee differentiability at $a$?" But your comments below also seem to simply seek a function which *is* and has these properties, not that they imply it.

Comment: Im not a english speaker, so im not beeing so clear, i guess,  i will change again the statement

Answer (score 1):

No, $f$ need not be differentiable at $a$. Consider the function
$$
f(x) := \mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)
$$
on $\mathbb{R}$. Clearly, $f(0) = 1$ and for each $H > 0$ there exists a rational number $x \in (0,H)$ such that $f(x) = 1 = f(0)$. However, because $f$ is nowhere continuous, it cannot be differentiable at $0$.

---

**Edit**. OP has changed the question and also added the condition that for every $G > 0$ there exists a point $y \in (a,a+G)$ such that $f(y) \neq f(a)$. By the density of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, we see that the function $f$ defined above also satisfies this property.

However, there does indeed exist a function satisfying both these requirements that *is* differentiable at $a$. Consider the function $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
f(x) := \begin{cases}
x^2 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q},\\
0 & \text{if } x \notin \mathbb{Q}.
\end{cases}
$$
It is not too hard to check that $f$ is differentiable at $0$. Moreover, an argument similar to that used above shows that this function satisfies both required properties at $a=0$.

Comment: Sorry, i miss some part, now I edited right

Comment: @LeoMartosBarbosa The function given in my answer satisfies both these properties, so the answer is still negative.

Comment: Yeah, i ve seen, but could i find any function thst is differentiable, with this characteristics iv said?

Comment: @LeoMartosBarbosa I'm confused, your question asks if you can ensure that $f$ is differentiable at $a$. Are you instead asking if there exists at least one differentiable function with these properties? If so, see my edit.

Comment: Yeah, im asking if exist at least one, i will edit, sorry again

Comment: Wow this question is becoming a real roller coaster, isn't it

Answer (score 1):

No. All this means is that the is a decreasing sequence of points $x_n\to a$ on which $f$ is constant. $f$ could take any value everywhere else.

For example, put $S=\{1/n\mid n\in \mathbb N\}\cup\{0\}$ and define $f=\chi_S$ (characteristic function which is $1$ on $S$ and $0$ elsewhere). Now consider $a=0$.

---

**Addendum:** (OP has changed the question) The conditions you specify neither guarantee nor prohibit differentiability at $a$.

Consider also $g(x)=x^2\sin \tfrac1x$, which is differentiable at $0$ (defining $g(0)=0$).

Both $f$ and $g$ satisfy your conditions (taking $a=0$), while $g$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f$ is not.

Comment: Sorry i missed some part, now i edited right